# Bash call external command and return control on exit

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there a proper way to call an external command or script in Bash, wait for completion, and return control back to the calling script? What I am seeing is that when the external script exits, it just drops to a shell without returning control:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ "${RUNAGAIN,,}" != *"no"* ]]
do
    $cmd="source ./otherscript.sh"
    fg $cmd

    echo "Do you want to run again?"
    read RUNAGAIN
done
```

Comment: plain `./otherscript.sh` doesn't work?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you want is the normal behavior when Bash executes a command.  Your example makes it weird, though, by using the `source` command to read an external script and run it in *the current* shell.

Comment: Also, I don't think the `fg` command is doing anything useful for you.

Comment: Run your code through shellcheck.net.  The assignment to `cmd` isn't valid, so it isn't defined and `fg $cmd` is identical to `fg`.

Comment: The source part is because i need to get variables from the second script and use them in the first script once script #2 completes.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) *("I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!")*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Running just "source ./externalscript.sh" did the trick for me. Not sure why it wasn;t working to begin with, but everything is good now.

Comment: Why did you think it *would* or *should* work the other way? (If you described that in the question, perhaps someone could add an answer that addressed that misconception directly). `fg` is job control -- a feature that's usually turned off by default in noninteractive shells to begin with -- and its argument is a jobspec -- a job number or a pattern describing an already-running background job; if you haven't started any background jobs (and in the above you haven't), it does nothing.